# How to delete the last image from carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, carrierwave

How to delete the last image from [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) gem if we're deleting one by one using this [procedure](http://bobintornado.github.io/rails/2015/12/29/Multiple-Images-Uploading-With-CarrierWave-and-PostgreSQL-Array.html#step-5-implement-remove-single-image-feature)

```
@gallery = Gallery.find(params[:gallery_id])
remain_images = @gallery.images
deleted_image = remain_images.delete_at(index)
deleted_image.try(:remove!)
@gallery.images = remain_images
```

The above will not delete the reference on the active record model for the very last image, because assigning `nil` to it when deleting the last one doesn't persist.

Answer (score 2):

just enter `@gallery.remove_images!`
This applies for multiple file uploads.